# Reorder values across multiple columns by defined sort criterion

Tags: r, sorting, data-wrangling

I have character data like these:

```
a<-"cat,hammer,green"
b<-"hammer,green"
c<-"cat,hammer,green"
d<-"cat, green"
e<-"green,cat"
f<-"hammer"
df<-data.frame(Col1=rbind(a,b,c,d,e))
df<-as.data.frame(str_split(df$Col1,",",simplify=TRUE))
df
```

The order of the columns SHOULD be cat, hammer green; however, my data have missing values and in some cases, the animal-tool-color column order is mixed up.  How can I define the correct order and then get my dataframe to have animals, tools and color in the proper column, and with NA values as shown below?

```
cat hammer green
NA  hammer green
cat hammer green
cat NA     green
cat NA     green
NA  hammer NA
```

Comment: what do you have to differentiate cat from hammer ? do you have a list of animals or/and a list of tools ?

Comment: I have a reference of the expected order:  `ref_order=c("cat","hammer","green")`    how can I use this to get the result I need?  Also, FYI, my "real" data have a reference order with 9 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way:

```r
a<-"cat,hammer,green"
b<-"hammer,green"
c<-"cat,hammer,green"
d<-"cat, green"
e<-"green,cat"
f<-"hammer"
df<-data.frame(Col1=rbind(a,b,c,d,e,f))
cond <- t(sapply(strsplit(df$Col1,","), function(x) c("cat", "hammer", "green") %in% x))
df2 <- data.frame(animal="cat", tool = "hammer", color = "green")[rep(1, nrow(df)),]
df2[!cond] <- NA
df2
#>     animal   tool color
#> 1      cat hammer green
#> 1.1   <NA> hammer green
#> 1.2    cat hammer green
#> 1.3    cat   <NA>  <NA>
#> 1.4    cat   <NA> green
#> 1.5   <NA> hammer  <NA>
```

Comment: Bravo moodymudskipper. Excellent!